# My computer is leaking memory all over the place. How do I fix it?

Tags: windows-7, memory, memory-leaks

So some months ago my computer started using more and more ram. The longer I leave it up the more it uses. This is to be expected but not at these rates. I have 12gbs of ram installed and after a few hours almost all of it is being eaten by some unknown source. I've tried looking multiple times but I've found no solution to my problem.

I'd like to thank everyone in advance here's what I'm running.

Windows 7 64bit Ultimate,
12GBs of ram,
Core i5,
2x GTX 550 Ti (I don't know why this matters but I'll include it).

Here's what I've found from searching, but I have no idea what they are or how to remove them.

[image]

Comment: Sounds like some buggy kernel-mode driver is leaking large amounts of memory. I can't really say for sure what's going on, though...

Comment: do you use a broadcom Wifi adapter? If yes, update the driver or stop the program BCMWLTRY.EXE.

Answer (score 0):

Try running cmd > **fltmc** and see what show up.  Maybe you can update the drivers on the list to see if the memory leak stops.  I had an issue similar to this before and it was due to old aksdf driver (Aladdin security device).